# Typescript: Programatically create type declarations file from object at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

## Problem

So I've been trying to use the node module `node-gtk` to create apps, but I'm running into a data typing issue. `node-gtk` allows you to import GTK modules, but Intellisense can't pick up what methods and properties exist on this module.

Example

```js
import * as gi from "node-gtk";

const Gtk = gi.require("Gtk", "3.0"); // Gtk is defined as `any`

console.log(Gtk) // 1000+ methods and properties
```

When I decide to log the Gtk module variable, 1000s of properties and methods are logged to the console. So here is my question: **How would one go about creating a type file from a variable at runtime?**

## What I've already tried

### JSON

```js
fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify(Gtk));
```

This sadly doesn't show any method information.

### Generating using `typeof` and iteration

```js
fs.appendFileSync("types.d.ts", "interface Gtk {\n");
for (let key in Gtk) {
  let type = String(typeof Gtk[key]);
  type = type == "function" ? "Function" : type;
  fs.appendFileSync("types.d.ts", `\t${key}: ${type}\n`, {encoding: "utf-8"});
}

fs.appendFileSync("types.d.ts", "}");
```

This does get us one step closer, but I have no further data about what the parameters and return types for functions are, class constructor params, object properties, etc...

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title - it's misleading. Interfaces cannot be created at runtime, because they simply don't exist then. However, it seems that is not actually your question, is it?

Comment: Oh yes, my apologies, I have changed it to something a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

> How would one go about creating a type file from a variable at runtime?

You would read the documentation for the code and write type definitions and optionally contribute them back to the community.

## More

TypeScript docs on creating declaration files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: I want to contribute them back, but given that there are thousands of properties and methods, I was wondering if I could iterate through the object and generate a types file from that. From that I wanted to create a public module for anyone else with a daunting task like this.